# Safe to delete a branch on Github if it's commits are in another branch?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

Simply put, if you have a `master` branch, and let's say you split off a branch under that:

`master/mybranch1`

You make some commits in this branch, la la la. And then you decide you need to make a "sub- branch" under `mybranch1` (ie, you run `checkout -B mybranch1/mysubbranch1` while in the `mybranch1` branch)

`master/mybranch1/mysubbranch1`

You make some commits to this sub-branch.

Now.. is it safe to use Github's "delete branch" button to delete `mybranch1` without it blowing away it's commits and the "sub-branch"? I'd want to the sub-branch to remain, and still be able to be merged into `master`.

Hopefully this question makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Deleting a branch never deletes a commit; it simply deletes a pointer to the commit at the head of the branch. As long as the commits reachable by the branch head are reachable from somewhere else, you're fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's safe.  Anything you do to a branch has no effect on any other branches, even if those other branches were derived from the affected branch.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is always safe to do this in this situation.

Your hierarchical branch names - if they are really your branch names - are just an (unusual) convention, and have no effect on the behaviour of git.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We try and always "nest" sub-branches underneath other ones, using naming conventions. I thought we had a good practice there but it sounds like we don't. What do you suggest/use yourself?

Comment: In fact, I recommend that you stop calling them (or even thinking of them as) "sub-branches."  There's no such thing, and you're confusing the issue.  Someone might think that you're talking about submodules, which are different beasts entirely.

Comment: Is there a name for such branches.. I guess a "derived" branch?